# Como Obtener los datos de una DBy ponerlos en los input para poder modificarlos con Ajax y PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

```js
$('tbody').on('click', '.modificarBtn', function(){   
   var vidToUpdate = $(this).data('idest');
   $.ajax({
    url: 'update.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {vidToUpdate: vidToUpdate},
    success:function(data){
     $('tbody').html('');
     $.each(data, function(index, value){
      var fila = '<tr id="'+value['id']+'"><td>'+ value['Nombre'] +'</td><td>'+ value['Apellidos'] +'</td><td>'+value['cedula']+'</td><td><button class="btn btn-danger eliminarBtn" data-idest = "'+value['id']+'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button> <button class="btn btn-primary modificarBtn" data-idest = "'+value['id']+'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button></td></tr>';
      $('tbody').append(fila);
      $('#contador').html($('tbody tr').length);
     });
     $('#contador').html($('tbody tr').length);     
    },
    dataType: 'json',
   });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Consolidacion</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="row" style="margin-top: 150px;">
 <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
 <div class="col-lg-5">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="nombre"> Nombre:</label>
   <input type="text col-lg-12" id="nombre">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="apellido"> Apellido:</label>
   <input type="text" id="apellido">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="cedula"> Cedula:</label>
   <input type="text" id="cedula">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="adiconarTbl"> Adicionar</button>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-6">
  <button class="btn btn-warning" > Cantidad en tabla: <span class="badge" id="contador">0</span> </button>

  <table class="table" border="1">
   <thead>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellidos</th>
    <th>Cedula</th>
    <th>Accion</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    
   </tbody>        
  </table>
 </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html


/Codigo Update

<?php 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "data_estudiantes";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());    
}

$didToUpdate = $_POST['idToUpdate'];

$sql = "select from estudiantes where id = " . $didToUpdate;
$resultado = $conn->query($sql);

$estudiantes =conn_fetch_array($resultado);
$nombre=$estudiantes['nombre'];
$apellidos=$estudiantes['apellidos'];
$cedula=$estudiantes['cedula'];

echo json_encode('nombre' => $nombre, 'apellidos' => $apellidos, 'cedula' => $cedula);
?>
```

Comment: Hola @V.Rocha, debes concretar un poco tu pregunta. Únicamente con el título no es suficiente para saber cual es tu problema.

Comment: Seria bueno que agregaras mas descripcion de tu problema para poderte dar la mejor solucion.

Answer (score 0):

Con jquery puedes acceder a los elementos html por medio de su id y cargar la data enviada a ajax con la función val() de jquery:

```
$('tbody').on('click', '.modificarBtn', function(){     
    var vidToUpdate = $(this).data('idest');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'update.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {vidToUpdate: vidToUpdate},
        success:function(data){
            $('input#nombre').val(data.value) #en vez data.value pones el valor que le quieres asignar a cada input, yo utilice data.value como ejemplo pero no se si funciona
        },
        dataType: 'json',
     });
 });
```

Te recomiendo no crear variables innecesarias, si ya tienes: `$resultado = $conn->query($sql);` para que utilizas `$estudiantes =conn_fetch_array($resultado);` ?
 prueba con `$nombre=$resultado.nombre;` y si te funciona elimina `$estudiantes =conn_fetch_array($resultado);`, tomalo un como consejo